# How to adjust a floated element's position?

Tags: html, css

I have a `ul` wrapped in a `.box`. I have set the bottom border for the `.box`. The `ul` items also have bottom border, I want the `li` border to place over the `.box` border so that the `.box` border is no more visible. I'm trying to do that by setting `margin-bottom: -1px` but doesn't work.

Please see attached image:

[image]

Here's what I'm trying:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>Hello</li>
         <li>World</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li{
    float: left;
    background: green;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/b9H2j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

You basically want the `li` to overflow its `.box` parent, but `.box` is set with `overflow:hidden;`.

**Solution**

A possible solution can be to first set the `li` with `position:relative;` and then make it overflow with `bottom:-1px;`. Then remove `overflow:hidden;` from the `.box` container and find an alternative way to overcome the clear bug.

For example:

```
.box {
    display:table; /* overcome the clear bug */
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue; 
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    position:relative;
    bottom:-1px;
    float: left;
    background: green;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

### See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b9H2j/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered changing your HTML structure? It seems somewhat to me "unnatural" to do what you're trying to achieve with your current HTMl. Anyhow, here's another solution. It requires you to set a height for your list items though.

You could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
<ul>
    <li class="left">Hello</li>
     <li class="left">World</li>
    <li class="add-bottom-border">something</li>
</ul>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    display:table; /* overcome the clear bug */
    width:100%;

}

ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li{
    height:20px;
    background: green;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.add-bottom-border {
    overflow:auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;    

}

.left {
    float:left;    
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6kQu/)

There's en explanation of the reasoning behind overflow:auto; [here](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/).